# How to use jsconfig.json in React Native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, packaging

I have a `MStore` source and I read that code.
In this code use `jsconfig.json` file and in screens importing the components or screens with this structure:

```java
import { Home , Splash , Login } from '@containers';
```

this is the `jsconfig.json` file, stored in location `MyReactNativeProject/src/`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src/",
    "paths": {
      "@common": ["common"],
      "@containers": ["containers"],
      "@components": ["components"],
      "@navigation": ["navigation"],
      "@images": ["images"],
      "@services": ["services"],
      "@utils": ["utils"],
      "@redux": ["redux"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

how can I use this config and this importing these components in my project?

Comment: Just use the whole configuration as a JavaScript file. just an opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with babel.config.js or .babelrc file as [it's here](https://github.com/iran-react-community/elegant-react-native/blob/master/babel.config.js)

You need to include [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver)